# Error 1064 when creating table in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm trying to create a table in my schema (`mydb`) called `employee`, but whenever I try running the script to create the table I get error #1064.

I'm new to SQL so I was looking at examples on how to create tables and went off those examples to create my own until I bumped into this error. Could anyone explain why I am getting this error message please?

MySQL Workbench Community 8.0 Version 8.0.26:

```
CREATE TABLE 'mydb'.'employee' 
(
    'emp#' INT PRIMARY KEY,
    'firstname' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    'surname' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    'salary' INT default 0,
    'city' VARCHAR(20),
    UNIQUE(firstname, surname)
);
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mydb'.'employee' ( 'emp#' INT Primary key, 'firstname' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 's' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the because you are adding `'` single quotes in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, you need to do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.employee 
(
    emp INT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    salary INT default 0,
    city VARCHAR(20),
    UNIQUE(firstname, surname)
);
```

If you need the quotes in Mysql you need to use the curly single quote like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`employee` 
(
    `emp_id` INT PRIMARY KEY,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `surname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `salary` INT default 0,
    `city` VARCHAR(20),
    UNIQUE(firstname, surname)
);
```

Also instead of using `#`, use `_id` or `no` you can check the following reference about [MySQL Naming Rules](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/mysqlguide4.1-5.0/0672326736/ch02lev1sec1.html)